# making onItemSelected visible to entire class

Tags: java, android

I'm new to this android/java stuff. I have this onItemSelected that will toast what has been selected in the spinner. I want to have the string resumeTableName accessible throughout my entire class that has the value of the selected spinner object. Right now it toasts the selected value however at other places in my class the resumeTableName remains null. I thought the public modifier would make it visible. How do I make this visible, do I use some sort of return?

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item

  String resumeTableName = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();



 // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),  resumeTableName,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `static String resumeTableName;`  declared in  your class and 
in your `onItemSelected` write

```
    @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item

  resumeTableName = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();



 // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),  resumeTableName,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

In this way the value of `resumeTableName` updated by the method will be the same for the whole class.

Comment: This works.Thanks a bunch. I'll vote as soon as it comes available!

Answer (score 0):

If You are new in Android programming there is a nice solution for the problems with visibility of variables.

You have to create class in your package:

```
public class GlobalVar extends Application{

private  int dummy1;

public int getDummy1() {
    return dummy1;
}
public void setDummy1(int dummy1) {
    this.dummy1 = dummy1;
}
}
```

then in any place in Your application You can get/set this data, by using:

```
GlobalVar gV = (GlobalVar)GetApplicationContext();
```

and then You just modify them by using Getters/Setters or any public methods from this class. I think it's very good solution for set of variables that You use often from different places of code.